# Lambda function for optimization in Lisp

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

Consider the following function definition in Lisp:

```
(defun f (l)
    (cond
        ((null l) 0)
        ((> (f (car l)) 2) (+ (car l) (f (cdr l))))
        (T (f (car l)))
    )
)
```

Give a solution to avoid the double recursive call `(f (car l))`. You will not use set,setq,setf. Justify the answer.

This is how I proceeded:

```
(defun f2 (l)
    (cond
        ((null l) 0)
        ((lambda (x) 
           (cond
                ((> x 2) (+ (car l) (f2 (cdr l))))
                (T x)
           )
         ) (f2 (car l)) 
        )
    )
)
```

I want to hear some opinions. By the way, it's just an exercise. This function is not suposed to do something coherent.

Comment: It would help everyone, yourself included, if you worked on formatting your code more carefully. Idiomatic Lisp doesn't look anything like what you have, for good reason. Start by stopping the scattering of parentheses over multiple lines; parenths are not semicolons, and Lisp isn't C. Now, did `f2` even compile when you tried to verify that `f` and `f2` have the same behavior?

Comment: It doesn't compile, but is an exercise. I have put the parantheses in order to see where things begin and close, I see it more readable.

Comment: "It doesn't compile, but is an exercise." the exercise is about producing correct code, thought, a compiler can help you do that

Comment: @hackermanwasd -- `f` compiles, but `f2` does not: this is a hint that something is wrong and that the transformation was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried to reformat your code in a Lisp way:

```
(defun f2 (l)
  (cond
    ((null l) 0)
    ((lambda (x)
       (> x 2)
       (+ (car l) (f (cdr l)))
       (T (f (car l))))
     (f (car l)))))
```

The use of `lambda` is fine to compute a value once and bind it to a variable, and it in fact you can merge the two last original cases of `cond` inside the lambda.

But, there are multiple problems which makes the code incorrect.

- recursive calls should call `f2`, not `f`
- you can't move the test clauses of the `cond` inside the `lambda`, this is not how the Lisp syntax works. You probably only need an `if`, but if missed a `cond` inside the lambda for the `(> x 2)` case.
- inside the `lambda`, do not call `(f2 (car l))` since the whole intent of using an intermediate function is to use the parameter `x` (this is about the `(T (f (car l)))` form which looks like a cond clause but is interpreted as a function call)

Comment: Why not f2 everywhere? So you don't use 2 functions in parallel

Comment: I did a refactor to use f2 everywhere

Comment: Isn't it ok now?

Comment: no, your cond is ill-formed, please try running the code with a lisp interpreter, like sbcl (steel bank common lisp), ecl (embedded common lisp) or even with emacs, since the subset of code that you are using is also valid as emacs-lisp

Comment: Edited, hope is fine now. Usually I write Common Lisp in Visual Studio Code and run it in the command line with "clisp program.lisp". Never used other IDEs, but I may try others in the future

Comment: this looks good but I think the F function alread is very strange (how can the result with other than zero?) but F2 does the same thing